# Как на PHP сгенерировать заголовок E-tag файла аналогичный заголовку который генерирует Apache версии Apache/2.4.6?

Tags: php, кэширование, header, http-заголовки

Пишу кешер для сайта, нужна функция на PHP которая бы вычисляла заголовок E-tag аналогичный тому который для него же вычислит Apache 2.4.6.

В Интернете нашёл вот такую функцию, при этом результат она выдаёт не тот

```
function calculate_etag($filename)
{
  return sprintf('%x-%x-%x', fileinode($filename), filesize($filename), filemtime($filename) );
}
```

Например для некоторого файла функция указанная выше выдаёт результат: 80ce57-7096-63492f3d, а apache для того же файла E-tag заголовок: 7096-5eafb750c8940.

Если операционная система имеет значение, то требуется для CentOs 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getETag($address=false) {
  if (($address !== false) and is_file($address)) {
    $f = escapeshellarg($address);
    $stat = `/usr/bin/stat --format %y $f`;
    if ((($pos = strpos($stat,".")) !== false) and (strlen($stat) > (pos+6))) {
      $fs = stat($address);
      return sprintf('"%x-%s"',$fs['size'],base_convert(str_pad(($fs['mtime'].substr($stat,($pos+1),6)),16,"0"),10,16));
    }
  }
  return false;
}

var_dump(getETag("imagex/example.jpg"));
```

Код отсюда http://blog.ivru.net/?id=298 там же подробности

Тут же добавлю что для вычисления Etag потребуется дата с микросекундами, штатных механизмов получения даты с микросекундами в PHP видимо нет, поэтому используется обращение к /usr/bin/stat чтобы получить значение даты аналогичное тому что возвращает операционная система с использованием команды stat.